# Compilation error - member already defined

Tags: c#, .net

Help and clarify me... why error occurred?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       

    }

    public int GetNames(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }

    public float GetNames(int id)
    {
        return (float)id;
    }

    public String GetNames(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two methods with the same name and the same parameter types.

Comment: Looks like a console application. Your method's need to have **static** in them, just as your Main method does.

Answer (score 11):

You can't have methods which have same signature. Return value is not a part of method's signature. Signature defined by method name and input parameters. So you have two methods with same signature:

```
GetNames(int)
```

See [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on msdn

> A return type of a method is not part of the signature of the method
>   for the purposes of method overloading.

Solution - make signatures different (rename methods, change parameter type of method, or change parameters number)